# Unable to change upload_max_filesize in php.ini

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

Running PhP v. 5.6.12 on localhost after extracting xampp-win32-v. 5.6.12.0-VC.7z through xampp control panel v. 3.2.1 with administrator rights on Windows 7 Ultimate (64-bit).

After editing php.ini in the php folder in xampp to change upload_max_filesize, phpinfo() shows no change of default value i.e. 2M. Checked phpinfo() through xampp and by creating a test file also. Same value of 2M is displayed.

Searched all concerned forums, but same old solutions didn't solve the problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you're changing the CORRECT .ini file. phpinfo() tells you which one was loaded, and where it is. and you have to restart apache after changing the file. the file's not monitored for changes, and is only parsed when apache starts up.

Comment: first restart the webserver, then if nothing changes try to look for another php.ini file on your computer, maybe in the windows folder.

Comment: Been there. Done that :-(

Comment: make sure that you are editing correct php.ini file. You should need to edit the php.ini file which was showing here: "Loaded Configuration File "

Comment: @jibon57 - As I have already mentioned in my OP, I have tried all the old solutions from all the concerned forums. Any new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing solution to help others having similar problems. Editing the original php.ini file in Notepad++ v. 6.8.3  didn't have any effect. Therefore, copied contents of the original php.ini file and pasted it to create a new php.ini file in Notepad++ itself. Changed the required values and saved. Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

Like yourself, I tried all the available solutions with no success so I figured why not to delete the file and create a new one from scratch. And voila it worked.

I use Visual Code Studio but it should work with other file editors.